# Can change in position due to acceleration be expressed using dual quaternions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, complex-numbers, grassmann-numbers, clifford-algebra

[Dual quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion) seem like an appealing way to model 6DOF motion since they linearize rotation.

I've reviewed what literature I can find on then, and found expressions for translation and change in position for constant velocity, but not for accelerating bodies.

Can change in position over time due to acceleration be expressed using dual quaternions or does the lack of a second derivative (over the dual numbers) make this impossible?

I've seen references to a more general [Clifford 'Motor Algebra'](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=clifford+motor+algebra)? Does it solve this problem?

Edit:

I am primarily working from the paper: ["3D kinematics using dual quaternions: theory and applications in neuroscience"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3576712/) which contains a tutorial covering screw translation and velocity using dual quaternions.

Comment: I briefly researched, but why do you say "lack of second derivative". It appears that as long as you are considering a rigid body a system of dual quaternions would be complete for 6DOF motion.

Comment: It's my understanding based on (e.g.) [this question about analysis] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341535/is-the-theory-of-dual-numbers-strong-enough-to-develop-real-analysis-and-does-i)  that the second derivative of a function over the dual numbers is not well defined. Whether this applies to the (unit) dual quaternions, I don't know.

Comment: Geometric Algebra has proven very useful in treating rotation. It is to my knowledge a generalisation of quaternions and their Clifford Algebra, even contains them as a subset. See e.g. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometric-Algebra-Physicists-Chris-Doran/dp/0521715954

Comment: Dual numbers are well suited for kinematics, but not very well suited for dynamics. I don't remember the reason, but I did look at them 10 years ago and came to this conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible. However, the displacement, velocity, and acceleration cannot all be represented in the same dual quaternion.

Dual numbers are often used to represent a quantity along with its derivative. This usage does not allow for a second derivative to be stored alongside it. The [primary paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3576712/) decided to store velocity quaternions along with their displacement quaternions in dual quaternions. However, one can simply store the displacement, velocity, and acceleration all in different variables. This is how the paper treats line velocities since the line itself took up too many degrees of freedom to store the velocity with the line in the same dual quaternion.

All of that said, acceleration isn't a particularly useful quantity when modeling 6 degree of freedom inertial movement. This is because forces and torques are proportional to the derivative of momentum not velocity. This distinction is only relevant for objects that have non-isotropic inertia tensors, and thus is easily forgotten. This distinction, means one should track momentum, and directly calculate velocity from that, rather than calculating acceleration.